# Using sed from Makefile

Tags: makefile

In a **Makefile** I'm trying to do the following:

Here I'm getting a couple things I need:

```
    S3_BUCKET_NAME_STATE=$(shell terraform output -json | jq '.S3_Bucket.value')
    DYNAMODB_LOCK=$(shell terraform output -json | jq '.dynamo_db_lock.value')
```

And with the result of that (i.e.: the content in the variables) I want to do some replacements in a file, like this:

```
    sed 's/{{ BUCKET_NAME }}/$$(S3_BUCKET_NAME_STATE)/g;' variables.tf.template > variables.tf)
```

But it keeps on not doing it right. I've tried using `${}` instead but i can't make it work...

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention whether these are make variables or shell variables, so I'm going to assume they're make variables.

Here's a working example of how to do this. It has 3 files: `test.json`, `variables.tf.template`, and `Makefile`.

Makefile:

```
S3_BUCKET_NAME_STATE := $(shell cat test.json | jq -r '.S3_Bucket.value')

all:
    sed 's/{{ BUCKET_NAME }}/$(S3_BUCKET_NAME_STATE)/g;' variables.tf.template > variables.tf
```

test.json:

```json
{"S3_Bucket": {"value": "Foo"}}
```

variables.tf.template:

```
some stuff {{ BUCKET_NAME }}
```

I made the following changes:

1. Using `:=` instead of `=`. The equals operator is the lazy substitution operator, which expands the macro at the time that it's used rather than at the time of defintion.
2. Using -r with jq. This gets the raw string value.
3. Using `$(var)` instead of `$$(var)`. Make interprets a double dollar sign as an escaped dollar sign.

I tested this on GNU Make 3.81 and 4.3.

Comment: thanks for the answer, this actually doesn't really work, since i'm using := the variables are set on startup and and actually empty. I need to set them _AFTER_ terraform apply, please see EDIT.

Comment: i just reformulated the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69031957/makefile-variable-manipulation