# Makefile variable manipulation

Tags: variables, makefile

I'm doing this:

```
apply: init
    @terraform apply -auto-approve
    BUCKET=$(shell terraform output -json | jq '.S3_Bucket.value')
    DYNAMODB=$(shell terraform output -json | jq '.dynamo_db_lock.value')
    @echo $${BUCKET}
```

make shows both variables being set (I was using := but that doesn't work for me, since i need them set when i execute `apply`) but it's still echoing blank:

```
...
Outputs:

S3_Bucket = "bucket1"
dynamo_db_lock = "dyna1"
BUCKET="bucket"
DYNAMODB="dyna1"
    <-- echo should print it out here
```

I want to use that variable for a sed afterwards...

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each makefile recipe line is run in its own shell.  Thus, shell variables set in one recipe line will not effect other recipe lines.   You can get around this by catenating all the lines as so:

```
 apply: init
    @terraform apply -auto-approve
    @BUCKET=$(shell terraform output -json | jq '.S3_Bucket.value'); \
     DYNAMODB=$(shell terraform output -json | jq '.dynamo_db_lock.value'); \
     echo $${BUCKET}
```

Comment: In general it's bad to use make's `shell` function inside recipes.  A recipe is already running in a shell and using make's `shell` function is unneeded and can lead to confusing results.  I recommend replacing `$(shell ...)` with either `$$(...)` or else using backquotes if you prefer to avoid the `$$`

Comment: That's very interesting, I had not understood that to be the case (every line is its own shell!) I'm going to try that, thanks!